# offsetHeight of $element becomes 0 when it's caught by an event when it shouldn't be

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to calculate offsetHeight difference between a child and parent element. But both *parentHeight* and *tableHeight* is zero here.

I can check the difference with *angular.element('parent-table')[0].offsetHeight* on console and it gives the correct value.

You might ask "why don't you use the angular.element selector then?". I can't, because this is a reusable directive, and there are many usages in the same page, and I am curious why it gives zero when it is clearly not.

I suspect somehow it loses the data when it goes async because of $scope.$on, but how and why?

Also code below is in controller but, it works the same in the directive.

```
$scope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function(ngRepeatFinishedEvent) {
  $window.setTimeout(function () {
    if(!vm.paging && vm.horizontalScrolling) {
      if(getOverflowHeight()) {
        console.log("rows overflow by " + getOverflowHeight());
      }
    }
  }, 500);
});

function getOverflowHeight() {
  var parentHeight = $element.find('.parent-table')[0].offsetHeight;
  var tableHeight = $element.find('.parent-table table')[0].offsetHeight;
  var difference = tableHeight - parentHeight;

  if(difference > 0) {
    return difference
  }
  return false;
}
```

ngRepeatFinished directive:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myModule') .directive('onFinishRender', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        if (scope.$last === true) {
          $timeout(function () {
            scope.$emit(attr.onFinishRender);
          });
        }
      }
    };
  }])
})();
```